# Why is new Number("3") === new Number("3") false?

Tags: javascript, constructor

Why does

```js
console.log(new Number("3") === new Number("3"));
```

return false?

Similarly, why is

```js
console.log(new Number("3") == new Number("3"))
```

also false?

Comment: because they are different objects (because you are using `new` it is constructing number Objects, not just coercing the strings to numbers) see: [Creating Number objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/Number#creating_number_objects) it's directly covered in the examples

Comment: I see - so since I'm comparing objects, it will not coerce the objects into values and return true? Weird how objects created with new Number() doesn't coerce in this case...

Comment: @WanderingDoge Both operands have the same type; no coercion ever happens in this case.

Comment: All objects never equal, unless there the same object. Your creating 2 number objects.   `new Number(3)` is not the same as the native type `3`..

Comment: What's the point of this anyway? Comparing two `int` values should not use `Number` at all.

Comment: Seems like a.toFixed() === b.toFixed(), so that any manipulation to return an actual value (even though it is from different objects) will return a numerical value - so I get it now that I should extract the value first, from the object, instead of directly comparing two objects. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/Number):

> The Number() constructor creates a Number object.

This means that you're checking for the equality of two objects. To check for the primitive values, you can use [`Number#valueOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/valueOf):

```js
console.log(
  (new Number("3")).valueOf() === (new Number("3")).valueOf()
);
```

Comment: This is incorrect.  You should ***never*** use `new` before `Number()`: http://linterrors.com/js/do-not-use-a-as-a-constructor

Comment: @HoldOffHunger That's out of the scope of the question, the issue is related to OP using the constructor.

Comment: This is the appropriate solution, imho: `console.log(Number("3") == Number("3"))`.

Comment: Ok, but that doesn't clarify OP's question. Thanks for sharing this, it would be beneficial as well.

Comment: @HoldOffHunger The whole point is that the OP *is* using the constructor, leading to the confusion. Your comments would be better expressed as a comment to the OP or as an answer.

Comment: @DaveNewton You can't answer a closed question.  That is why I put the comment here. P.S. (Not the downvoter here, not that it should matter.)  You have enough rep to reopen it, right?  I can add the answer if you do that.

Comment: @DaveNewton It most certainly was.  By Certain Performance and then now by VLAZ.

Comment: @HoldOffHunger Why does the question need to be reopened? What part of it is not covered either in the three duplicates currently linked to it, nor at all in any other place on SO over the more than a decade since it was created?

Comment: @VLAZ: I'm not the one who said it wasn't or shouldn't be closed.  Feel free to direct your questions to that person with an `@` at their name, thanks.  (Please don't @ me for someone else's questions.)

Comment: @HoldOffHunger [you've also voted to reopen the question when it was first closed](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70546107/timeline#history_502abc20-e931-42a7-b27c-2b2d6fe962d5).